# Long-Time Behaviour - Inverse Laplace Transformation

Tags: asymptotics, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I already did research a lot but didn't find any solutions for my problem.

I have a complex function $F(s)$ but can't solve for f(t) via the inverse Laplace-Transformation. I assume there is no analytical way.

Anyways: I'm just interested in the long time behaviour of $f(t)$, aka how the dependence is as $t\rightarrow \infty$ (it should go like $t^{-a}$).

Is there any approach/lemma/theorem I can use, but at this point im kind of desperate.

To give the actual problem:

$F(s)=1/(s+G(s))$ and $G(s)=\mathcal{L}\left[(A\exp{\omega_0t})/(1/ \omega_0+it)^2\right]$

Comment: $G(s)$ ist the inverse transform of a function of $t$? Are you sure you don't mean that it is the Laplace transform and not the inverse?

Comment: yes, you are right, thanks! I edited it